Prove that $ \text{Out}(F_2) \cong \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$
Let $F_2$ be a free group of rank $2$. Define: $\text{Out}(F_2)=\text{Aut}(F_2) / \text{Inn}(F_2)$.
Prove that:
$$ \text{Out}(F_2) \cong \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$$

In previous exercise, I showed that:
$$\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) = \langle a,b,c \mid  b^6, c^2, a^{2}b^{3}, (bc)^2, (ac)^2 \rangle$$
where
$ a = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix} $ ,
$ b = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix} $ ,
$ c = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} $ .
I also showed that there is a homomorphism $\Phi : \text{Aut}(F_2) \rightarrow \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, that maps every automorphism $\varphi$ on $F_2=F(x,y)$ to a matrix $M$ in $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, as follows:

$M_{1,1}$ is the sum of powers of the $x$'s in $\varphi(x)$
$M_{2,1}$ is the sum of powers of the $y$'s in $\varphi(x)$
$M_{1,2}$ is the sum of powers of the $x$'s in $\varphi(y)$
$M_{2,2}$ is the sum of powers of the $y$'s in $\varphi(y)$

For instance, if we define:
$f: x \mapsto y^{-1}, y \mapsto x$
$g: x \mapsto y^{-1}, y \mapsto xy$
$h: x \mapsto y, y \mapsto x$
Then $f,g,h \in \text{Aut}(F_2)$, and $\Phi (f) = a$, $\Phi (g) = b$, $\Phi (h) = c$ .
Now, clearly $\Phi$ is a surjective, and $\text{Inn}(F_2) \le \text{ker}(\Phi)$. I need to prove that $\text{Inn}(F_2) \ge \text{ker}(\Phi)$ .
It's easy to show that $g^6, h^2, f^2g^3, (gh)^2, (fh)^2$ are all in $\text{Inn}(F_2)$, but is it enough? I guess I can find more automorphisms on $F_2$ that are mapped to $a,b,c$ under $\Phi$. Can I show that $\text{ker}(\Phi)$ is generated by $f,g,h$, or is there another way?
Thanks!

Also, by a theorem of Lyndon Schupp we have $Out(F_2)\cong Aut(F_2^{ab})\cong Aut(\Bbb Z^2)\cong GL_2(\Bbb Z)$.

I think this is usually credited to Nielsen, who showed the natural map $Out(F_n)\rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is always surjective, and is injective precisely when $n<3$. Can you say where the exercise is from? Knowing what you're working with would be super helpful in suggesting an approach.

You refer to a previous exercise.  From this, I infer a sequence of exercises, as if from a textbook.  If they are from such a book, please share in an [edit] which book you're using; it will help future users of this site.

Hi, it's from homework and not a book, but I think you can find a proof in the book "Combinatorial Group Theory" (by Roger C. Lyndon , Paul E. Schupp), which unfortunately I don't own. Should be in chapter 4 acoording to Google Books.

There is a more modern approach to this problem, applying the concept of a train track representative of an element of $\text{Out}(F_2)$.

Your argument is good, and is in fact the same one given in Lyndon & Schupp. IMO, however, both are missing a piece.
Suppose you have two groups $G=\langle U\mid R\rangle$ and $H=\langle V\mid S\rangle$ and a homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$. You also have some elements $\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}$ which map onto $V=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$. And finally you have a normal subgroup $N\lhd \ker(f)$ such that each relator in $S$ (treated as a word over the $g_i$) is in $N$. This is not enough to show the kernel of $f$ is $N$. Consider the case $G=\langle a,b\mid b^2\rangle$ and $H=\langle c\mid c^2\rangle$, with $a\mapsto 1$ and $b\mapsto c$. Then trying to apply the above logic to $\{b\}$ would have you conclude $\ker=\{1\}$, which is of course untrue.
The missing piece is showing the $\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}$ generate $G$. When that's true, then what you want to claim is true (since it allows you to define a surjective inverse to $f$). In your specific case, you need to show $\{f,g,h\}$ generate $Aut(F_2)$.

Got it. I can prove that actually, thanks!
